# Don't know what callback URL I should use?

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, postman

What should I enter for callback URL when trying to generate a new access token in Postman? I'm using a Client ID and Client Secret from my Twitter Developer account.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same callback URL that you registered on Twitter when generating a client ID and secret. If you haven't provided any URL there, then you can use anything (e.g. `http://localhost`).

If you're calling the token endpoint from postman (as I think you are), so you want to exchange the code for tokens, then you should use the same callback URL that you used in your authorization request.

Comment: What code for tokens?

Comment: What does the request look like in Postman, that you're trying to execute? Did you register any callback URL on Twitter when you were getting a client ID and secret from the Twitter developer account?